# Show text based on customer group

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I am using BigCommerce. Currently a customer will login and be redirected to their account page. I would like to display some text on the account page but only show the text if they are in the customer group "vip".

I know that the global variable bigcommerce use for customer groups is %%GLOBAL_CustomerGroupName%% - I just wouldn't know how to set this up to actually work.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Kind regards

Tried {{if}} but it doesn't work for the set up I am using on BigCommerce

Comment: change the tag to BigCommerce to get relevant help

Comment: Can you edit your question to post any code that you currently have?

Comment: I don't currently have any code @JCollier... I found some code someone else used that looked like it might do the trick if it was modified some to show text rather than to show/hide "coupon code box".. .the code was:

<div id="groupname" name="groupname" class="hide">%%GLOBAL_CustomerGroupName%%</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
if ($("div#groupname").text() != "Retail Grower")
$(".CheckoutRedeemCoupon").toggleClass("hide");
else
$("#CheckoutRedeemCoupon").show();
})
</script>

Answer (score 0):

The %%GLOBAL_CustomerGroupName%% variable is for Blueprint themes, and it sounds like you may be using Stencil. Your approach began correctly with using an {{if}} in Handlebars, you'll need to use a Stencil object instead of a Blueprint variable:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/reference-docs/other-objects-and-properties-overview#other-objects_customer

Comment: Hello @Kyle O'Brien ... I can confirm that I am using the Blueprint theme and it is not possible for me to make the switch to Stencil at this time. Is there a way to achieve the desired result on Blueprint using JS? thank you :)

Comment: Hey there @tommyboy87 the code you sent should work on Blueprint themes, something to note is you will need to specify the group name where it says "Retail Grower" with your own group. You can find which templates allow global variables here: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/legacy/blueprint-themes/global-variables


For example, Panels/SiteAccountMenu.html allows the %%GLOBAL_CustomerGroupName%% variable to be accessed and is a template that retains throughout the account area.

Comment: Hi @Kyle O'Brien - thank you, the code I posted is actually some one elses code and I really wanted it adapted. So for example, the code posted will hide the "coupon" box if user is within group "retail grower" ... what I want to do is have a code, which works on the same principle but will display a selection of text if the user is in the group "vip" ... what I don't know how to do, is how to adapt the above code so that it doesn't reference whether a coupon box displays or not but rather if a selection of text displays or not based on customer group. I hope this makes sense, thanks

Comment: @tommyboy87 It looks like there's a toggleClass method included in that code, where it says CheckoutRedeemCoupon which seems a likely culprit. I'd use that as your starting point and from there you can use your web browser's Inspector to find other elements that could be targeted instead.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding something simple such as the below example in the account template ?

```
{{#if customer_group_name '===' 'vip-group-name' }}

  <h2> Whatever text here! </h2>

{{/if}}
```

I've used something similar before and it worked. Hope that helps.